# pip install "parse error" when running in bash script

Tags: python, pip

I have a bash script to do pip install few packages.

```
#!/bin/bash
packages="pycparser cffi ipaddress enum34 cryptography asn1crypto"
pip install ${packages}
```

And i am seeing this error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'pycparser cffi ipaddress enum34 cryptography asn1crypto' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 252, in from_line
    req = Requirement(req)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 97, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8])) InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'cffi ipa'"
```

Everything is good when i run the command `pip install pycparser cffi ipaddress enum34 cryptography asn1crypto` on the terminal itself.

Anyone could help? Thanks.

Comment: I am able to run the provided script without problems. (using pip 9.0.1 for python 2.7)

Comment: Most probably it's some special char you have copied into the script from somewhere, or some no-break space. Analyze the script with `shellcheck` to verify the line is fine.

Comment: I have found the root cause, which at the beginning of script, there is IFS being set